# What are the frame formats and are compatible ethernet and 100 gigabit ethernet?

Tags: networking, ethernet

Good afternoon! Can anyone know what are the frame formats and are compatible ethernet and 100 gigabit ethernet?

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's not a programming question. You'll need to find networking documentation describing the various wire protocol details for ethernet.

Comment: Excuse me. Where i can ask the question or where to download the documentation?

Comment: I really can't say where this would be a valid question - pretty much any public discussion forum, twitter, reddit, etc. As far as where to download documentation? Again, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow (tool/product/documentation/offsite resource recommendation questions). Best bet is to do some searching on the internet. A search for "ethernet packet format explanation" seems to yield good information, and I'm sure there are plenty of other searches which will yield more links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frame formats for Ethernet are generally compatible throughout the Ethernet family - you can simply switch a frame from 100 Gbit/s to 10 Mbit/s. (You might need to do in two steps though as a 100G switch might not support as far back as 10M.)

You can get the offical standards directly from [IEEE 802.3](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/standards/get-program/page/series?id=68) (free, requires registration). The frame format is detailed in Clause 3 that you can find in IEEE 802.3 Section 1.

There are few extensions but you can worry about that later. Any link layer (L2) features are generally compatible with any physical layer (L1) defining medium and speed. Your hardware equipment defines what you can actually use.